# C++ class and function output issue

Tags: c++, function, class, cout

I'm having problems with my program's output. It keeps spitting out 12345.

Here's the details:
It's split in three files: program8.cpp (the part that runs tests), myRandom.cpp (implementation of the class), and myRandom.h (specification of the class).

**myRandom.h:**

```
#ifndef MYRANDOM_H_
#define MYRANDOM_H_
class myRandom
{
    public:
            myRandom();                         //Constructor
            ~myRandom();                        //Destructor
            void seed(unsigned long theSeed);   //Mutator for current
            unsigned long next();               //Mutator or Accessor for current
            int randInt(int start, int end);    //Scales result to a range
            double randNormal();                //Future expansion
    private:
            unsigned long current;                      //Current random #
            static const unsigned long a = 1103515245;  //Multiplier for LGC
            static const unsigned long c = 12345;       //Increment for LGC
            static const unsigned long m = 2147483648;  //Modulus for LGC
};
#endif /* MYRANDOM_H_ */
```

**myRandom.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "myRandom.h"

using namespace std;

myRandom::myRandom()                                        //Constructor
{
    current = 0;
}

myRandom::~myRandom()                                       //Destructor
{
}

void myRandom::seed(unsigned long theSeed)                  //Mutator for current
{
    if (theSeed < 0 || theSeed > m-1)
    {
        // ERROR
        return;
    }
    else
        current = theSeed;
}

unsigned long myRandom::next()                              //Mutator or Accessor for current
{
    if (current < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error: cannot set seed to a negative number" << endl;
        return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        current = (m*current+c)%m;                              //Formula
        return current;
    }
}

int myRandom::randInt(int start, int end)                   //Scales result to a range
{
    if (start >= end)
    {
        cout << "Error: cannot set start greater than or equal to end" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((this->next() % (end - start)) + start);
    }

}

double myRandom::randNormal()                               //Future expansion
{
    cout << "Warning: randNormal not implemented" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**program8.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "myRandom.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    myRandom theRand;
    unsigned long theSeed;

    cout << "Verify that the sequence generated by next() is the same on each run" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << theRand.next() << endl;
    }

    cout << "Verify that you can set the seed to 0 and 1" << endl;
    theSeed = 0;
    cout << theRand.next() << endl;
    theSeed = 1;
    cout << theRand.next() << endl;

    cout << "Verify that attempting to set the seed to -1 generates an error" << endl;
    theSeed = -1;
    cout << theRand.next() << endl;

    cout << "Verify that you can set the seed to m-2 and m-1" << endl;
    theSeed = 2147483648-2;
    cout << theRand.next() << endl;
    theSeed = 2147483648-1;
    cout << theRand.next() << endl;

    cout << "Verify that attempting to set the seed to m generates and error" << endl;
    theSeed = 2147483648;
    cout << theRand.next() << endl;

    cout << "Verify that next() produces a sequence predicted by hand/calc for the chosen seed" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a seed: ";
    cin >> theSeed;
    cout << theRand.next() << endl;

    cout << "Verify that using start == end generates and error. Set both to 10." << endl;
    theRand.randInt(10,10);
    cout << theRand.next() << endl;

    cout << "Verify that using start > end generates and error. Set start to 10 and end to 5." << endl;
    theRand.randInt(10,5);
    cout << theRand.next() << endl;

    theRand.seed(theSeed);
    cout << "Testing randInt for start=0 end=1,000" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << theRand.randInt(0 , 1000) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem lies in the next() function, since that's what gets called all those times in program8.cpp cout statements. I could understand getting 12345 once, but it should be updated once that function runs successive times. I apologize if it's a dumb question. Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't a code specific one - it is Math-related from here:

```
current = (m*current+c)%m;
```

This *always* returns the value of `c` if `c < m`, otherwise (or more generally) it returns `c % m`. Why? From this theorem:

```
(m*n + a)%m = a
```

Example:

```
m = 10
n = 3
a = 7
(10*3 + 7)%10 = 7
```

See this for more:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Well, this always returns `c` only if `c < m`.

Comment: You can see it this way: `(m * current + c) % m` = `((m * current) % m) + c % m` = `0 + c % m`. :)

Comment: @Jefffrey: You're very correct - thanks for mentioning that. I've edited it. :)

Comment: So to fix this, I can just check if c < m, and if it's not, run the formula, otherwise return an error?

Comment: Note that your theorem is correct in maths, but for some reason computer science does weird things with negative numbers and it won't work. In particular if you choose a negative `n`.

Comment: @user3479352: From your code, `c` and `m` are fixed, so to "fix" this if you will, you have to either generate a new number to take the place of either `c` or `m`. How you do this is entirely up to you as looking at your code - and I could be wrong about this - it seems that you're trying to implement a custom random number generator.

Comment: @jrd1: Right you are. I just remembered that they're static. I am trying to implement my linear congruential generator from an earlier program. It looks something like this: 

seed = (multiplier*seed+increment)%modulus;

Comment: @Cramer: You're very correct - it's up to the OP to figure out the methodology behind implementing that.

Comment: @user3479352: Cool! However, unfortunately I am not well versed in cryptography schemes, so I don't know how much more help I can be. But, if my answer was useful to you, please consider it for acceptance. :)